# sorting in wpf using entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am testing the workings of WPF with Entity Framework. I have a SS table called `Vendors {VendorCode, VendorName, Phone}`.

I am sticking with only EF and I am able to display and navigate the recordset on a WPF form with buttons first, next, last etc.  I used the instructions on the MSDN site (Create a simple data application with WPF and Entity Framework 6)

My problem is the recordset is sorted only in the order it was entered into SS.  I would like to sort it by VendorCode or by VendorName to make it easier on the user.  I can't seem to make it sort the recordset or table data coming through EF.

Can you please help? Thank you!

#### Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public Vendor newVendor { get; set; }
VendorsEntities context = new VendorsEntities();
CollectionViewSource VendorViewSource;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    newVendor = new Vendor();
    VendorViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource) 
                         (FindResource("VendorViewSource")));
    DataContext = this;
}
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // this next line doesn't do it
    context.Vendors.OrderBy(Vendor => Vendor.VendorCode);
    context.Vendors.Load();
    VendorViewSource.Source = context.Vendors.Local;
}
private void NextCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VendorViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting context, not displayed items. Try:

```
VendorViewSource.Source = context.Vendors.OrderBy(Vendor => Vendor.VendorCode);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This works indeed, except I had to squeeze in the 'Local' as follows: VendorViewSource.Source = context.Vendors.Local.OrderBy(Vendor => Vendor.VendorCode);

Answer (score 3):

You would need to set the result of `OrderBy` method in to some variable and then use that as `OrderBy` will return a new reference, or you can use the set the reference of `context.Vendors` to the reference returned by `OrderBy()` method.

Try doing it like:

```
   var ordered = context.Vendors.OrderBy(Vendor => Vendor.VendorCode);
   VendorViewSource.Source = ordered;
```

another way can be to order it after bringing the result back, but it is not a recommended approach, first approach should be preferred, but just giving another option which is also possible:

```
var vendors = context.Vendors.Load().OrderBy(Vendor => Vendor.VendorCode);
VendorViewSource.Source = vendors;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!  This first solution also works great but I had to squeeze in the 'Local' as follows: var ordered = context.Vendors.Local.OrderBy(Vendor => Vendor.VendorCode);